# Best approach for requesting the number of records in table with REST

Tags: java, rest

With /api/v1/account/names I request all the names in my DB but what if I need to know the number of records (names)? (for paging)

Which approach of the the following REST-Urls would you recommend:

1. /api/v1/account/names/count
2. /api/v1/account/names?count - (does not work well with Jersey)
3. /api/v1/account/names/records
4. your suggestion...

The Result of api/v1/account/names and the one for api/v1/account/names#whatever#
is different.

thx

Comment: and what if that count will change between your count request and data request?

Comment: Maybe that's another approach - avoid this call at all. It's probably the best one. I stuck so much on the idea of requesting the number of records that I overlooked this problem. Can you write an answer so that I can rate you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paging, you should not do a count query but query everything at once: the count and the page records.

On your DB, issue something like (PGSQL like syntax - fetching the 3rd page of 25 records where column 4 value is 'x')

```
Select
       row1, row2, row3, count(*) over()
       from MyShema.MyTable
       where row4 = 'x' order by row1 asc
       offset 75 limit 25;
```

The resultset will contain the total count on the 4th column (of every row).

Then build a Json response that would look like

```
{
   totalCount: 1280,     -- value in row 1 column 4
   offset: 75,
   rows: [
      [row1_1, row1_2,row1_3],
      [row2_1, row2_2,row2_3],
       ...
      [row25_1, row25_2,row25_3],
   ]
}
```

which contains the total number of rows a the time of query, the offset and the page content.

This response can easily be processed by a paging grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is to combine both of these requests in one and return the number of entries, say, in header of response to ensure that entries and their count were retrieved in the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I accepted BGRs answer - it's the same but a bit more detailed...

Answer (score 0):

If `GET /api/v1/account/names` returns the list of names:

```
{
  "names": ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
}
```

then why not but a `count` element into this list:

```
{
  "names": ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"],
  "count": 3
}
```

You could request this sub-resource as `GET  /api/v1/account/names/count`:

```
{
  "count": 3
}
```